# Comparable Company Selection

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, nlp, deep-learning

I have been at this problem for a while, let me explain.  I would like to find companies with similar business models, i.e. they do similar things.  I have searched for various ways to model out companies based on their business description to compare which companies are most similar.  So far, I have looked at semantic textual similarity utilizing neural networks (Link to a paper at the end) and other nlp techniques, although the first seems most promising.

If I have a corpus of documents, each document being the business description of a company...

Company 1: Manufactures maintains and repairs truck bodies in the United States It manufactures truck bodies...

Company 2: Offers help desk and warranty insurance administration services for various industries The company also offers service programs for the consumer electronics and the heating ventilating and air conditioning HVAC industries...

Company 3: ...

etc.

And I have a target company, we'll say...

Company T: Engages in identifying evaluating and qualifying potential natural gas and oil wells...

I would like to find which companies out of corpus have the most similar business models to the target company.

What are some good ways that I could go about doing this?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

How about calculating a TFIDF score for each  company description and then calculate TFIDF score for the target company. Find companies with similar TFIDF score of the target company.

Comment: I have definitely thought about this, and attempted to implement, but the problem is that word frequency doesn't always play a part in comparing the descriptions.  For industrial companies this would work great, but for the more nebulous descriptions of tech companies, very comparable companies my not have much in common with their business descriptions. For example, Facebook and Apple are quite comparable even though one business description will talk about mobile hardware and the other about social media.  I need something to understand what the text is talking about on an abstract level.

Comment: I would like to understand what factors determine that Apple and facebook have similar business models. I mean on what basis are you saying that these two companies are having a similar business model.

Comment: I apologize, the true comparison I am looking for is companies that tend to experience similar market affects, which can be represented by growth rate, size, and innovation etc.  Business descriptions are just a good way of finding companies that seem to be similar as companies that operate in the same market tend to be so.  Industry classifications can be helpful, but not as much as comparing descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

The success of the employed technique depends on multiple questions. I wouldn't argue about importance of other aspects, but the three that come to my mind are the following.

1. How many descriptions or examples do you have? And how heterogeneous is your dataset?

This crucially influences the model choice. For instance, if you have a good guess about the number of distinct company types, you can use LDA (Latent Dirichlet Allocation) with k topics, where k is your guess on the number of types. You can then use the trained model to infer topic distributions and, using some divergence measure like Kullback-Leibler divergence, find similar company descriptions. 
If you have no clue about the number of company types, try out hierarchical LDA, where you don't need to specify the number of topics.
There are plenty implementations of LDA in Java, R, python and so on. 
However, this will most likely not work well if you have a highly heterogeneous dataset with only few instances per type.

2. Do you have a predefined keyword set distinguishing among company types?

If so, you can use the above technique to extend your keyword set as it gives you clusters of terms that often coocur. You may then try out a simple rule based approach where you just count the number of common terms.
If you don't have such a set, there's an approach by Tomokiyo and Hurst that might help you learn them (link to the​ paper below).  But again, you would need to be able to split your dataset by topic beforehand.

3. Labels

Have you tried a supervised approach by manually labeling some of the descriptions? You may also look at active learning models if that is too cumbersome.

http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1119287

Comment: First, aplz, thank you for the response.  The set does have predefined groups done by industry that the company operates in, and I have compiled about 30,000 descriptions.  The industry classifications are defined as follows: Apple is defined as "Technology Hardware" and Amazon as "Internet and Direct Marketing Retail".  My problem is that, to find truly comparable companies, they need to have similar volatility in their business models, which can be related to size and other aspects of the company.  Hence, Amazon and Apple are very comparable, but different industries.

Comment: In what way could I create a utilize the similarity in business descriptions, which tend to be better than industry classification, and other metrics such as size? Is there a weighted approach you know of?